# how to 'getelementsbytagname.onclick'

Tags: javascript, html, getelementsbytagname, clonenode

I am trying to get my `cloneNode` to append the `input` tag and give it a new `onclick` value.  Its just the `input.onclick = function(){clicker(iden);};` that doesn't work.  The sole purpose of this example is to change the onclick tag like I managed to change the ID.  Can anyone please help?

**Script**

```
<script>
  iden = 0

  function clicker(x) {
    iden++

    var ent = document.getElementById('ent').cloneNode(true);

    ent.id = "ent"+iden;
    var input = ent.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];

    input.id = "inp"+iden;
    input.onclick = function(){clicker(iden);};

    document.body.appendChild(ent);
  }
</script>
```

**Body**

```
<body>
  <div id="ent">
    <input id="inp" onclick="clicker()">
  </div>
<body>
```

Comment: i see no issue with your code : http://jsfiddle.net/8hD7g/1/

Comment: @aslan: The sole purpose of this example is to change the onclick tag like I managed to change the ID.

Comment: I would suggest ending the lines, that it would be appropriate to do so, with a semicolon. Good practice.

Comment: Uh! I see what I did wrong.  I was using the Chrome Developer to view the source to see if the cloned code was physically updated.  The onclick was doing what it was meant to do but still showed the old value. Strange really.

Comment: @JasperJohns : onclick of a input tag should clone new,
on which tag is clicked, that tags clone should be taken, is that you want ???
check:
http://jsfiddle.net/aslancods/Lb4Gh/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the

```
function () {
```

At the bottom of your  tag fixed it for me

```
<html>
<body>
    <script>
    iden = 0

    function clicker(x) {
        iden++

        var ent = document.getElementById('ent').cloneNode(true);

        ent.id = "ent"+iden;
        var input = ent.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];

        input.id = "inp"+iden;
        input.onclick = function(){
            clicker(iden);
        };

        document.body.appendChild(ent);
    }
    </script>
    <div id="ent">
    <input id="inp" onclick="clicker()">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well spotted, that was accidental though. I have amended it but the sole purpose of this example is to change the onclick tag like I managed to change the ID

Answer (score 1):

**JS :**

```
function clicker(iden) {  
    iden = (!iden) ?  '' : iden;


    var ent = document.getElementById('ent'+ iden ).cloneNode(true);
    iden++;
    ent.id = "ent" + iden;

    var input = ent.childNodes[1];
    input.id = "inp" + iden;

    input.onclick = function () {
        clicker(iden);
    };

    document.body.appendChild(ent);
}
```

**HTML :**

```
<div id="ent">
    <input id="inp" onclick="clicker()">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're only trying to change the onlick attribute using `setAttribute` would work:

```
input.setAttribute("onclick", "clicker(" + iden + ");");
```